# Does anyone know what is this error when I try to compile on MonoDevelop?

Tags: ubuntu, mono, compiler-errors, monodevelop

When I try to compile the solution I got this error:

```
Error CS1902: Invalid debug option `+'. Valid options are `full' or `pdbonly' (CS1902) (TAG)
```

See the error from IDE:

[image: MonoDevelop compile error]

More about this error:

```
MonoDoc exited with a exit code = 1.
```

End I don't know if this another error is related, when I run `monodoc`:

```
$ monodoc
grep: /etc/gre.d/*.conf: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado (file or directory not found)

Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Monodoc.EditMerger' from assembly 'monodoc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Monodoc.EditMerger' from assembly 'monodoc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it's well-known problem. If you are using your custom Makefile for compilation just remove "+" key from it. Like here:
https://github.com/OpenRA/OpenRA/pull/2596/files

This is affected only for compilation debug version, so you can change target from "Debug|x86" to "Release|x86" (at least it helps for me).